# How to use Spring Data JPA example matcher with additional conditions

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use the Example of Spring JPA to do the search. With the following code, most of it fits the requirements.

```
public Page<Shop> findShops(Shop condition, Pageable pageable) {
        ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching().withStringMatcher(StringMatcher.CONTAINING).withIgnoreCase();
        return shopDao.findAll(Example.of(condition, matcher), pageable);
    }
```

In addition, I ONLY need the SHOP with status NOT equals DELETED.
Something like, `.withMatcher("status", notEqual())`
or maybe  `.withMatcher("status", contains())` a list.

I am not sure if and how Example Matcher could do such thing. 
Could anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

For the one `WHERE` clause you dont need QBE. Query from method should be enough:

```
Page<Shop> findByStatusNot(String status, Pageable page);
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: Thank you for reply. I know QBE could do everything, It looks like ExampleMatcher is more user friendly in this case since I want to search the SHOP which matches the example (condition) but with some additional condition. I don't know if QBE and Example could work together or not. Anyway has any idea?

Comment: Thank you for reply. It is not one single condition. All values in condition SHOP will be used and , in additional, status is also required with an "Not EQUAL".